# Get coordinates of bounding polygon of a location in google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I want to be able to obtain coordinates of the vertices of a polygon bounding a particular area (locality) in Google maps.

For eg. if I enter :

HSR Layout ( a locality in Bangalore, India) in Google maps it shows a polygon bounding the area.

I found out its not possible with Google Maps Api v3, but use of KML layers might help. Can someone please explain this.

Comment: No, as far as I know Google does not provide these boundaries to the API; you can't get them as an object.  I hope I'm wrong, I would like these too.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay You cannot get them directly through the API. However, the API does facilitate the importation of such data in the form of .kml.

Comment: @Shivendra Have you got any workaround for the same?

Comment: @user2129794 L No. I went with the same approach involving KML overlay files

Comment: @ShivendraSoni can you share that as an answer so that it can help others

Comment: @ShivendraSoni: from where do you source the KML files for Bangalore?

Answer (score 1):

If the KML data is available online, then you can access it using `google.maps.KmlLayer`. Please see an example here (you will probably understand it; it is a very simple example): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.

```
//make an instance of google.maps.KmlLayer, using the URL with the desired KML data.
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
});

//set the KmlLayer to a map
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

Again, the usage of this function is very simple.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on how to extract these coordinates in the first place from a map? The method you described above plots a boundary on map using a KML file, which already has the coordinates we need to extract.

Comment: @haywire At the time that I wrote the post, it was not possible to get boundary data from Google Maps (as far as I knew). Therefore, one needs to use external KML data.